# logging memory usage of each process

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a way to log the amount of memory used by each process in linux?  One of our servers has a memory usage spike that brings down the machine from time to time and the logging would really help us find the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

If your needs aren't very complex perhaps you could make do with `ps` and a while loop:

```
while true; do date; ps auxw --sort rss | tail -n 10; echo; sleep 60; done >> logfile
```

This logs the top ten processes (by memory use) every minute.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest solution would be to put in a cron job which does something similar to

```
ps auxww | logger -p local0.info -t ps
```

This would log `ps` output through your logging daemon to the local0 facility (can be changed to whatever you want)

Answer (score 0):

Here follow a couple of suggestions on how to diagnose a memory spike that causes [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) on a server, using a tool I wrote for Linux process analysis, [Procpath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Procpath).

The most obvious ad-hoc diagnostic is to record all process' metrics and when the issue occurs again to take a look at the recordings. This can be done, for example, in a terminal multiplexor like [Byobu](https://www.byobu.org/) (with least effort to make it run in the background).

```
procpath record -i 60 -d all.sqlite
```

This will produce an SQLite database and record Procfs metrics for each process there every minute. Post-mortem you can query the database, say for the PIDs that consumed from than 10% of available main memory (RSS measured in pages).

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT stat_pid
FROM record
WHERE 1.0 * stat_rss / (SELECT value FROM meta WHERE key = 'physical_pages') > 0.1
```

And plot a PID's RSS growth chart.

```
procpath plot -d all.sqlite -q rss -p $PID
```

Alternatively if you want to take metrics more often, say because the spike is quick, and to avoid ending up with a big SQLite database, you can:

- record only relevant process subtree(s) (e.g. `$ROOT_PID` and its descendants):

  ```
  procpath record -i 10 -d tree.sqlite "$..children[?(@.stat.pid == $ROOT_PID)]"
  ```

  You may be able to ask your process supervisor (systemd, supervisord, etc)
  for the PID.
- record only processes that consume more that X MiB (say 256 MiB which
  typically equals to 65536 memory pages):

  ```
  procpath query '$..children[?(@.stat.rss > 65536 and @.pop\("children", 1\))]'
  ```

  `@.pop("children", 1)` is there to get rid of descendants of the matched
  process unless they themselves match.

If either produces a few PIDs in the database, you may be able to analyse them visually with `procpath plot` right away.